# Populate an iframe with json data

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, iframe

I have a requirement of populating an iframe (HTML component) with a json data. I have a java script  function which on page load loads the json data. But, the iframe component is not able to load the data.

My code implementation is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.loadJSON.js"></script>
<script>
function populateData()
{
window.document.getElementById('one').style.color='red';
var data = {"d1":"http://www.w3schools.com/"};
$('form').loadJSON(data);            
alert('start');
}

window.onload = populateData;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label id="one" for="Address">Address:</label>

    <iframe id="d1" width="100%" height="50%" src="about:blank">
        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
    </iframe>
    <br> <br>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
function populateData()
{
$('iframe#d1').attr('src',"https://maps.google.com/maps?&output=embed");           

}
```

Just change the `src` attribute on the iframe. No need, or use, for JSON here.

As far as I can tell, the url you're querying returns HTML, and not JSON. You just want to show the map, yeah?

Comment: Thank you for the response. But my requiremnet is not to load a map, but, instead I want to load any given url in the iframe. The data is dynamically loaded on to the HTML from a json object.
The elements on the HTML form is not fixed and hence I cannot explicitly set the value as mentioned by you. Is there any other way i can achieve the binding of the url to an iframe.